# Masking data after a particular word up to next word in oracle

Tags: oracle

I was facing issue during masking a data that is describe below --

|  | Input | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | CC# S2345-567 Match 2345 This is String | ************** Match 2345 This is String |
| 2. | My Self CC P457-238 This is Data | My Self *********** This is Data |
| 3. | My Card is CC 457829 | My Card is ********* |
| 4. | This is the CC# 42357 This is the my records | This is the ********* This is the my records . |

I was able to mask the 3rd and 4rd condition by using below query --

```
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN start_pos1 > 0 
       THEN SUBSTR( col, 1, start_pos1 - 1) 
            || RPAD('*', end_pos1 - start_pos1, '*') 
            || SUBSTR(col, end_pos1) 
       ELSE col 
       END AS col_new 
FROM   ( 
  SELECT col, 
         REGEXP_INSTR( col, 'CC([. # -]*\d+)+', 1, 1, 0, NULL) AS start_pos1, 
         REGEXP_INSTR( col, 'CC([. # -]*\d+)+', 1, 1, 1, NULL) AS end_pos1
 FROM  Table 
);
```

Can anyone please help for above the 1st and 2nd condition ?

Comment: We need more precise rules about masking your data in order to give an answer here.

Comment: After CC or CC# the next alpha-numeric number or numeric number can be masked and alphanumeric word can consist one character. for example       CC# S2345-567 Match 2345 This is String ---- ************** Match 2345 This is String
My Self CC P457-238 This is Data ----- My Self *********** This is Data

Comment: Just as a note, in general it would probably be better to _not_ mask with the exact original width of CC text.  The reason for this is that giving away the length might still be leaking critical information, e.g. what the type of credit card being used is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the alphabetic character before the digits:

```sql
SELECT col,
       CASE 
       WHEN start_pos1 > 0 
       THEN SUBSTR( col, 1, start_pos1 - 1) 
            || RPAD('*', end_pos1 - start_pos1, '*') 
            || SUBSTR(col, end_pos1) 
       ELSE col 
       END AS col_new 
FROM   ( 
  SELECT col, 
         REGEXP_INSTR( col, 'CC#?\s+[A-Z]?\d+([. -]*\d+)*', 1, 1, 0, NULL) AS start_pos1, 
         REGEXP_INSTR( col, 'CC#?\s+[A-Z]?\d+([. -]*\d+)*', 1, 1, 1, NULL) AS end_pos1
  FROM  table_name
);
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (col) AS
SELECT 'CC# S2345-567 Match 2345 This is String' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'My Self CC P457-238 This is Data' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'My Card is CC 457829' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This is the CC# 42357' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'The ABCC should not be masked' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COL | COL_NEW |
> | --- | --- |
> | CC# S2345-567 Match 2345 This is String | ************* Match 2345 This is String |
> | My Self CC P457-238 This is Data | My Self *********** This is Data |
> | My Card is CC 457829 | My Card is ********* |
> | This is the CC# 42357 | This is the ********* |
> | The ABCC should not be masked | The ABCC should not be masked |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f85aa10c10d65f383f6e57b265ded27c)*

Comment: Note that masking to the exact original width of the credit card number might be an issue as it may give away some information about the CC (e.g. which provider it is, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```sql
SELECT col,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(col, 'CC#?[[:space:]]+\S+', '********') AS col_masked
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Your query is working fine for above string . but for below it is failing for ex -                      1. CC#      F38967 is data . because of multiple spaces in between CC# and F38967 it was showing as it is.

Comment: @EX08 Please check the updated answer.

Comment: This will mask "ABCC should not be masked".

Answer (score 0):

One more alternative:

```
WITH cteData
  AS (SELECT col, REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'CC#? [A-Z]?[-0-9]+') AS MATCH_DATA
        FROM table_name)
SELECT col, MATCH_DATA, REPLACE(col, MATCH_DATA, RPAD('*', LENGTH(MATCH_DATA), '*'))
  FROM cteData
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4428912ae38461c6ae4b9eebbc0b58cf)

(And many thanks to @MT0 for the sample data :-)